# Why does one part of conditional statements in Python returns None while others are ok?

Tags: python, cs50

I need to write a code that prints out valid or invalid for an input of letters and numbers for a license plate. The conditions are: first two characters must be letters, characters have to be between 2 and 6, and if numbers are used, 0 should not be the first, nor should a number appear before a letter.

I put the code below on Thonny and cannot understand why `len(l) == 4` part of the conditional statement for `def valid_order()` returns `None` and does not execute the next line of the code whereas others work fine. My code should return "Valid" for CSAA50, but it returns invalid. Why?

Also, is there an elegant way to write `def valid_order()`?

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(s):
    if s[0:2].isalpha() and 6 >= len(s) >= 2 and s.isalnum() and valid_order(s):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def valid_order(c):
    n = []
    l = list(c[2:len(c)])

    for i in c:
        if i.isdigit():
            n += i
    if n and n[0] == "0":
        return False

    if len(l) == 2:
        if l[0].isdigit() and l[1].isalpha():
            return False
    if len(l) == 3:
        if l[0].isdigit():
            if l[1].isalpha() or l[2].isalpha():
                return False
        else:
            if l[1].isdigit() and l[2].isalpha():
                return False

    if len(l) == 4:
        if l[0].isdigit():
            if l[1].isalpha() or l[2].isalpha() or l[3].isalpha():
                return False
        else:
            if l[1].isdigit():
                if l[2].isalpha() or l[3].isalpha():
                    return False
            else:
                if l[2].isdigit() and l[3].isalpha():
                    return False
    else:
        return True

main()
```

Comment: What happens if `l[0].isdigit()` is true but  `if l[1].isalpha() or l[2].isalpha() or l[3].isalpha()` is false? And the same for the other similar sets of conditions.

Comment: Some of your `if` statements have no `else` statement. When the condition is false, you go to the end of the function. Since there's no `return` statement at the end, it returns `None` by default.

Comment: You could probably implement the whole thing using a couple of regular expressions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure what you mean by "len(l) == 4 part of the conditional statement". Do you mean, what happens in the conditional statement, when `len(l) == 4`? I also don't understand the reasoning behind "and does not execute the next line of the code whereas others work fine". What is "the next line of the code", in your understanding? Why do you think it is "not being executed", and why *should* it be?

Comment: "My code should return "Valid" for CSAA50, but it returns invalid. Why?" In order for it to get that result, `valid_order` would have to return `True`, yes? What input do you think should cause `valid_order` to return `True`? Step by step, *why* would that happen?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, after len(l) == 4: is condition executed, I expected the next line else: return True to be executed, but Thonny shows that when len(l) == 4 is executed, the code returns to def is-valid() rather than go to else: return True at the end, just before main().

Comment: @Barmar, your suggestion worked. I added another else: return True at the end of len(l) == 4: condition and now I get the desired result: input of CSAA50 yields the right output: Valid

Comment: Sorry, I think I just overlooked part of the code before, because I didn't notice the scroll bar. I don't understand what you mean by "another" `else: return True` though.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I meant adding it at the end of the if len(l) == 4: condition, right under the last if statement.